# GPT implementation for Instant Articles

Tags: google-dfp, google-publisher-tag, facebook-instant-articles

From what I understand, Facebook only supports an iframe adtag for DFP ads. Google states there are limitations with using this functionality, seen here: https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/90777?hl=en

We're hesitant to implement the iframe tag across our whole website just to satisfy Facebook's requirements as this would then impact direct website traffic.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone have a sample of what FB's desired implementation would look like with the use of the iframe GPT tags?
2. Is anyone currently doing this, and if so, have you implemented this site-wide (limiting website functionality), or are you using a REGEX to cut the original ad out and replace within your feed export - seems messy.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the link you shared and the FB policy it seems there aren't any real concerns with using an iframe.  FB doesn't allow expandables or 3rd party ads.  You can always have house ads targeting the ad unit as a fallback so i don't think the blank situation should come into play either.  Here's the Facebook policy for reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/policy